# Magento 2 Use Symlink In Default or Production Mode for Pub Static Files

Tags: magento-2.1

Situation: I am running some free trials of Magento 2 and have limited HD space on the VPS. For this reason to cut down on HD space I want to have Magento symlink the files in default or production mode. I have noticed that a default Magento 2 install is about 420mb once the site first runs it goes to around 770mb so 350mb of this is copied files.

I have modified: app/etc/di.xml line:

```
 <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

to

```
 <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

This works ok and the site will properly create the symlinks even when in default mode. However the issue is that the css is not created or the js-translation.json the files it should create but does not are:

```
/pub/static/version1488209436/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css

/pub/static/version1488209436/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css

/pub/static/version1488209436/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/print.css

/pub/static/version1488209436/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/js-translation.json
```

So the question is: how do I make Magento also generate these files when in default or production mode and using symlinks?

Comment: Perhaps you could use Gulp or Grunt to for the CSS issue: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162906/why-clear-pub-static-frontend-after-css-changes-in-dev-mode and look into the different modes for the js-translation.json file? https://gist.github.com/antonmakarenko/7538216

Comment: Thanks, I will up this to +100 if someone can give me step by step and verify it works.

Comment: inside pub/static folder there is a .htaccess file, which is responsible to rewrite the url and remove 'version1488209436' from url and provide an user friendly url. If .htaccess not working properly then only this type of issues occurred.

Comment: thank you @Tonmoy but it is not related to this at all. The issue is that the files don't generate because I'm using symlinks rather than copy while in default / production mode.

Comment: Since there are 4 files than you can create those symlinks manually or in a .sh script.

Comment: Btw make sure you configured production mode with both cli command magento `deploy:mode:set production` (app/etc/env.php) and in Nginx conf if is the case. You can see if production mode is set correctly if there `is not` the button `Flush Static Files Cache` in `Admin > System > Cache Management`

Comment: @obscure I would accept your answer if you showed what the .sh script commands would be to do this (create these missing files). I can't create the symlink manually because the files do not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`app/etc/di.xml`: add new item to `stategiesList`:

```
<virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
/* ++ */    <item name="asset" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Assuming you are in developer mode just delete the contents of `pub/static` and go to your page in the browser - magento will regenerate the static content.

**worked for me in Magento 2.1.4** (styles-m.css got generated and other files got symlinked).

all the magic happens in `vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/MaterializationStrategy/Factory.php`:

```
public function create(Asset\LocalInterface $asset)
{   
    if (empty($this->strategiesList)) {
        $this->strategiesList[] = $this->objectManager->get(self::DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
    }   

    foreach ($this->strategiesList as $strategy) {
        if ($strategy->isSupported($asset)) {
            return $strategy;
        }   
    }   

    throw new \LogicException('No materialization strategy is supported');
}
```

Magento just loops through `stategiesList` items and use the first stategy that supports the asset.

**How to make it work in production mode?**

**Disclaimer:** this hack contains core file editing. beware.

all tested on magento 2.1.4

1. remove version number from static files in `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Static Files Settings > No`
2. edit `vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php` and make `launch` function look like this:

   ```
   public function launch()
   {   
   // disabling profiling when retrieving static resource
   \Magento\Framework\Profiler::reset();
   $appMode = $this->state->getMode();
   /*if ($appMode == \Magento\Framework\App\State::MODE_PRODUCTION) {
       $this->response->setHttpResponseCode(404);
   } else {*/
       $path = $this->request->get('resource');
       $params = $this->parsePath($path);
       $this->state->setAreaCode($params['area']);
       $this->objectManager->configure($this->configLoader->load($params['area']));
       $file = $params['file'];
       unset($params['file']);
       $asset = $this->assetRepo->createAsset($file, $params);
       $this->response->setFilePath($asset->getSourceFile());
       $this->publisher->publish($asset);
   /*}*/
   return $this->response;
   }
   ```
3. delete contents of `pub/static` and visit your store url in a browser.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! Just that one line in the di.xml! Also I appreciate your explanation of how it works. Now the install is 482mb instead of 770mb which will save me money not having to upgrade my VPS free trial server.

Comment: you are very welcome sir I am glad it worked for you.

Comment: is it not just enough modify only StaticResource.php and keep the original app/etc/di.xml without adding `<item name="asset" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
`?

Answer (score 0):

When not in production mode Magento 2 will try to create symlinks for some static resources. You can change that behavior by doing the following.

1. Open up app/etc/di.xml and find the virtualType name="developerMaterialization" section. In that section you'll find an item name="view_preprocessed" that needs to be modified or deleted. You can modify it by changing the contents from Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
2. Delete the files under pub/static. Please dont delete the .htaccess file.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, I don't want to "copy" I want to "symlink" to save space with the limited server resources.