# Proper Magento 2.1 Frontend develop flow

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, less, grunt

I am approaching Magento 2 for some projects and I am trying to setup an efficient workflow for frontend developing.
So far I followed [this guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) to setup a theme with a blank theme as a parent.
I also followed [this other guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html) to setup Grunt.
As a bonus, i also reviewed all the steps and applied what was missing by following a third guide (bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer, static-deploy,...).

My problem is every time I edit my main less file I need to run a

```
grunt clean:theme && grunt exec:theme && grunt less:theme
```

Else I cannot see the edits when I refresh the page.
Grunt watch does not seem to help in the process, it does not update files at all. (Do I need to edit dev/tools/.../watch.js in some way?)
Running all three command slow down my process a lot, is there something I missed?

PS: Cache management is ON and Frontend development worflow is set to "Server side", on "Client side" I get strange CSS errors.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162907/36463

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by grunt exec:theme, that do not seem to create symlinks to the less file in app/design/Vendor/theme. Editing the file in /pub/... seems to work, any idea on how to solve the symlink problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good amount of research i found out what seems to be the problem/solution. I was using @import in my less files, it looks like the way i did it made grunt process and copy the files.
The right way `to @import` is:

```
@import '_myfile.less'
```

With single quotes, underscore as first character and .less extension.

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6943)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that for magento, the `app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/web/css/source/_extend.less` file will always be compiled into the core styles when you clear the `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed` folders or run the grunt command. You don't have to use any import statement there. When using a couple different less files in a project, this file can act as an aggregate for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences. First your should enable developer mode. Default I will enable all cache

 Local settings: use Server side less compile, No js combine, No css js minify

If i modify layout i will disable page_cache and layout.
Modify templates no need to clean cache if block is set `cacheable="false"`

**Change styles such as css ,less** I will remove these files in location

```
var/view_preprocessed/ <== your less file will linked here
pub/static/frontend/*
```

Modify javascript files no need to clean cache
I used chrome for local devtool. Open current modify in new chrome tab and reload everytime i modify it in order update latest my changed

Comment: I find the need to delete files/folders as a bad practice in a good workflow, it slows down everything, even if you just need to launch a single command.