# How to avoid repeated static-content-deploy & cache-clean for every UI level change in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Every time I change a bit of js, html or css, I end up cleaning cache, upgrade & reset permissions. Any solution to avoid all these things ?

PS:
Cache is disabled &
Developer mode is ON

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162907/36463

Comment: @BilalUsean by following that answer I still need to do some command line stuff. What I want is hassle free development. Change the code-> refresh the page -> changes are reflected. (While developing)

Comment: you need to use grunt for that case, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html